# Replacement for scroll-padding-top in IE (To enable regions to be correctly scrolled to)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When I have (for example) a validation summary on a form and click on the relevant `<a href="#error1">Error 1...</a>` tag with the error, the relevant field is scrolled to, but it is not correctly scrolled in view because the scroll value doesn't add on the pixels for the fixed header. I resolved this with ease in Chrome etc. by adding

```
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 150px;
}
```

However this doesn't work in IE. I've searched stack overflow but cannot find anything that works. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent for `scroll-padding-top` in CSS so we can't workaround it in IE just using CSS. In IE, we can calculate the offset of the element you want to reach then use jQuery to scroll to it when we click the link. The `onclick` function is like below:

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer
{
    var h1 = $("#error1").offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: h1 - 150 });
}
```

I also make a [simple sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/46n5kb21/) and you can refer to it. The results in IE and Chrome are the same.

Result in IE:

[image]

If it still can't solve your problem, please provide [a minimal, reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your situation so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: Thanks worked - just updated to use the href attibute.. `var h1 = $(e.target.hash).offset().top;` Thanks